# Does anyone know these non-LEGO bricks? dimples in studs, no connectors on the bottom

Tags: part-identification, set-identification, clone-brands, vintage

We found this box of old (definitely) non-LEGO  bricks in Czech Republic. Probably from the seventies or eighties?
Does anyone know the manufacturer - brand or set (s) from which they can be?
We thought it was Wundersteine (Wonderbricks), but their bricks are different.
Here are some photos, no visible logos.
Many thanks for any suggestions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is one of Eastern Germany's (DDR) two brick systems (created by typical [VEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkseigener_Betrieb)s and I'd be suprised if you find those letters anywhere printed on the bricks):

- most likely [Formo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formo) because of the simplicity of the backside and how basic all the bricks are - you should **not** be able to combine it with *Lego* bricks and these bricks are rather **difficult to impossible** to assemble. Or
- less likely [PEBE](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebe) because I've never encountered so large bricks for that, and in your pictures I see not one specialized brick although those weren't uncommon, while sets with only basic bricks were not typical - you should be **able** to combine it with *Lego* bricks and these bricks can be put together **without further problems**.

*PEBE*'s bricks looked different thru the years - what you show might be from 1980s, [because later the studs consisted of cylinders only](https://www.pebe-archiv.de/sets/2000.htm) (yet [still compatible with *Lego*](https://althofer.de/zusammen-waschen.html)). For i.e. 2x4 flat bricks without studs it was very typical to have not even one cylinder or stud on the backside.

*Formo*'s highlight was a set of the [Palast der Republik](http://www.puppenhausmuseum.de/ddr-spielzeug.html), intended to be bought as souvenir.